# Weighted table output in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, survey

I am trying to create a shiny app that would produce weighted tables using svytable for my variables of interest in the dataset. However, I do not get any output, returning error "object 'input' not found". Here is code to replicate my problem.

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = rnorm(20, 0, 1), col2 = rnorm(20, 2, 2), w = rnorm(20, 1, .2))
df.w <- svydesign(id = ~1, data = df, weights = ~w)

ui <- fluidPage(
        selectInput("v1", "Choose column", colnames(df), selected = "col1"),
        verbatimTextOutput("table")
)
server <- shinyServer(function(input,output){
  output$table <- renderPrint({
    svytable(~input$v1, df.w)
  })
})
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You recieve this error since `input$v1` is a string, but `svytable` expects a `formula`. You can convert strings to formulas using `as.formula`

```
library(shiny)
library(survey)

df <- data.frame(col1 = rnorm(20, 0, 1), col2 = rnorm(20, 2, 2), w = rnorm(20, 1, .2))
df.w <- svydesign(id = ~1, data = df, weights = ~w)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("v1", "Choose column", colnames(df), selected = "col1"),
  verbatimTextOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output$table <- renderPrint({
    myformula <- as.formula(paste0("~", input$v1))
    svytable(myformula, df.w)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I wonder how did you know this? Or better question, how could i have known? I am relatively new

Comment: This is actually a common problem. Formulas are always tricky when you want to create them "dynamically" like you did here. For debugging purposes (in shiny), you can call `browser()` inside your render functions (or `reactive` expressions).

Comment: Is there a way to save the df.w for later? My dataset is about 1GB and it could take a while to produce df.w, so it will save time and improve experience in shiny app I am developing.